# Android XML: android:elevation vs. app:elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-xml, android-5.1.1-lollipop

When do I use `android:elevation` and when `app:elevation`?

What's the difference between those two?

Comment: I googled, but did not find any useful results.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hope I can help, Let's talk with an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_medium"
    />
```

The `android:elevation`[attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)) will work from the API level 21 and upper.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
    app:elevation="@dimen/elevation_medium"
    />
```

In this case the `app:elevation` attribute belongs to the `FloatingActionButton` styleable, inside de [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) which will work from version 4 of the framework, instead version 21, the case of `android:elevation`.

Comment: The AppBarLayout has the app:elevation attribute but it still doesn't work. Seems like it disappeared in the recent support library updates.

Answer (score 19):

`app:elevation` - if you are using support library (for supporting old versions of Android)
`android:elevation` - if you are not using support library

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with all ViewGroup. For example, I'm using support library, but I'am not able to use the app:elevation with the toolbar.

Comment: I can't use `app:elevation` with LinearLayout too. But `ViewCompat.setElevation(View view, float elevation);` works.

Answer (score 2):

There is one more thing:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing"
    android:src="@drawable/svg_my_location"
    app:elevation="4dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_round_white"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
```

With using `app` `FloatingActionButton` is visible

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing"
    android:src="@drawable/svg_my_location"
    android:elevation="4dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_round_white"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
```

When you're using `android` `FloatingActionButton` is invisible, because it overlapped  by bottom sheet