# How to change app:elevation programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My app is work for API 19. So I can't use android:elevation. So I app:elevation in my layout.

[Android XML: android:elevation vs. app:elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054316/android-xml-androidelevation-vs-appelevation)

For exemple :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="5dp">
```

How to change app:elevation programmatically ? I can change android:elevation but I can't find how to change app:elevation !

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try with using the following code

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(View, float)
```

Following the below link. Here showed how to make elevation on pre-lollipop device

[Android AppCompat 21 Elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation/26747592#26747592)

Comment: Please describe here what would be the value of "View".

Comment: The 'View' would be the xml element to which you are trying to add the elevation to. For instance if you have ImageView or a LinearLayout with an android:id="@+id/my_custom_id" then the code would be 
ViewCompat.setElevation(my_custom_id, 15F)

Comment: This doesn't work with `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer won't actually work. The answer should have been updated.

If you look at why `mAppBarLayout.setTargetElevation(0)` is deprecated. it states that:

> @deprecated target elevation is now deprecated. 
>   AppBarLayout's elevation is now controlled via a {@link android.animation.StateListAnimator}. 
>   This method now always returns 0.

So to programmatically set the appbar layout you can only do it by creating a `StateListAnimator` such as `appbar_state_unelevated_animator` at the `animator` res folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="elevation"
        android:valueTo="4dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:duration="100"/>
</item>
```

then loading it in code like so:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        appbar.stateListAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(applicationContext, R.animator.appbar_state_unelevated_animator)
    }
```

If I'm not mistaken you could also create a `StateListAnimator` by code but don't take my word for it.

**Update:**

In my experience when you set the 
    app:elevation="//Any DP value//"

The Shadow of the app bar will be lost. Simple remove that line to get the appbar shadow again.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, especially with the Google documentation. But its not working for me. I really wonder why. Do you mind sharing a sample git project where this method is working? Or I can share mine here, if you're still tracking this issue...

Comment: You can share me yours coz, the code above is all you ever need to do this. There probably something which is specific to your implementation. Maybe I could help you with that. Go ahead and share me your code.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to provide updated and full answer:

```
    switch (state) {
        case On:
            appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.appbar_elevation_on));
            break;
        case Off:
            appBarLayout.setStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.appbar_elevation_off));
            break;
    }
```

appbar_elevation_on.xml under RES\animator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource">
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

appbar_elevation_off.xml under RES\animator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource">
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you for complete answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you try to change the elevation of the Action bar you can easily use this line, which will work on API 19

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

or you follow this link and check out how to change the elevation of views on Android below API 21 generally

[Android AppCompat 21 Elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728570/android-appcompat-21-elevation/26747592#26747592)

Comment: That's change android:elevation. Not what I want :x

Comment: No, that dosesn't work. I except for a setAppElevation or something else.

Comment: I just used it in a an app min api 15

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me.

To remove shadow in Toolbar use

`app:elevation="0"` in AppBarLayout xml or

use `mAppBarLayout.setTargetElevation(0)` in java.

It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is for NativeScript

```
let nativeAnView = tnsView.android;
var shape = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
shape.setShape(android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.OVAL);
shape.setColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor('#30bcff'));
nativeAnView.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
nativeAnView.setElevation(20);
```

on Android

```
let nativeView = tnsView.ios;
nativeView.layer.shadowColor = new Color('#888888').ios.CGColor;
nativeView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.0);
nativeView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
nativeView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
```

on iOS